# Retrieve ReportType in Visual Studio Code

Tags: custom-report-type, git, visualstudiocode

I am able to retrieve Email Templates in VIsual Studio Code as follows

```
  sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:"[FolderName]/[EmailTemplateDeveloperName"
```

I have tried searching, but can't find the command to retrieve 'Custom Report Types'

I am not able to retrieve Custom Report Type from the org browser. I don't see the new Custom Report Types I created under the menu ReportType as seen in the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Does  sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ReportType -u your_org_user_name not work?

Comment: Thanks @akarnid

The ReportTypes I was truing to add to the repo did not exist in the Dev Org. After I deployed those to the Devorg, I was able to retrieve those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ReportType
```

Comment: Thanks @Raul Pereyr

The ReportTypes I was truing to add to the repo did not exist in the Dev Org. After I deployed those to the Devorg, I was able to retrieve those.